# Javascript Regex for allowing alphanumeric Characters,comma, dots, spaces

Tags: javascript

In PHP, I used the following codes to  Remove special characters except **alphabets, numbers,comma, fullstop and space.**

```
$text = "test, 22222 @% test test test.";
$message = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9,. ]/', '', $text);
```

How can I achieve the same using javascript. I knew of javascript replace params below but its not giving me what I want

```
var text = "test, 22222 @% test test test.";

var message = text.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9,. ]/);
```

Comment: You're missing the 2nd argument 'replacement'? `text.replace(regex, "");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var text = "test, 22222 @% test test test.";
var message = text.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9,. ]/g, '');
```

- The key difference is that you need to add the g flag at the end of the regular expression to indicate global matching. This way, it will replace all occurrences of the specified characters in the input string.
- So, in the code above, any character that is not a letter (A-Za-z), number (0-9), comma, period (full stop), or space will be removed from the text string, and the result will be stored in the message variable.

  ```js
  function processText() {
    var originalText = document.getElementById("originalText").value;
    var processedText = originalText.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9, .]/g, '');
    document.getElementById("resultText").textContent = processedText;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <p>Original Text:</p>
  <textarea id="originalText" rows="4" cols="50">test, 22222 @% test test test.</textarea>

  <button onclick="processText()">Process Text</button>

  <p>Processed Text:</p>
  <p id="resultText"></p>
  ```